# Should I say "kick in $100 into somebody's account" or "kick $100 into somebody's account"?

Tags: prepositions

> - kick in $100 into somebody's account
> - kick $100 into somebody's account

The phrasal verb is 'kick in' (not just 'kick') but the prospect, effectively, to use 'in' twice arouses doubts in me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to kick in an amount to some thing = to contribute an amount to it.

Why are you interested in using that verb? Usually, kick in means contribute some amount of money to something. **Money is not usually kicked into an account.**

Money is kicked in as a contribution to buying someone a gift or to having a party, for example.

- I kicked in $`10 to the party fund.
- He kicked in $10 to buying John a retirement gift.

Comment: I need to translate this: 'закинул (kick in?) пару долларов (a couple of dollars) на счёт (into the account)'. 'Закинуть', in this case, means "put" but is informal and has the air of carelessness, often denotes an action done in passing, without much thought or planning beforehand. I try to retain those connotations. What's your suggestion?

Comment: to throw rubles into the account is what you are looking for.

Comment: I haven't found such a sense here (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/throw)

Comment: ***Lobbed, chucked,*** and ***threw** [in]* also occur with this slangy "contribute" sense. The preposition before the "destination" is often ***towards*** rather that ***[in]to***, which I think reflects that fact that any such contribution is usually just a ***fraction*** of the total (the implication being that others also ***chip in*** to get to some required amount).

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev You mean: I didn't find a meaning like that. Yes, some things cannot be found on the Internet, necessarily. Try another dictionary.